# Как соединить два шестнадцатеричных числа

Tags: c

В десятичной понятно. Есть 2 и 2, надо 22, первое умножаем на 10 и складываем. Но как сделать то же самое в шестнадцатеричной? F и F, чтобы стали FF. Таким же способом (умножая одно на F и складывая с другим), получается не то.

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами пишете, что `2` и `2` получаете от складывания `2` и `2*10`.
Так почему же при `F` и `F` вы пишете про умножение на `F` (15), а не `10` (16).

C 16 же всё то же самое, лишь умножение на 16, а не 10. Т.к. система счисления 16-я, а не 10-я.

А вот если результат и далее неправильный - ошибка в вашем коде.